# How to represent ZonedDateTime in OpenApi

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying get `ZonedDateTime` in my generated code from OpenApi.
There is a `If-Modified-Since` header that OpenApi generates on my endpoint but it's in the type of `LocalDateTime`. This is causing issues on my integration tests.

```
task buildEndpointsFromYAML(type: 
org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
generatorName = "spring"
inputSpec = acquirerYML
outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()

groupId = "$project.group"
id = "$project.name-java-client"
version = "$project.version"
apiPackage = "com.abc.xyz.apiEndpoints"
modelPackage = "com.abc.xyz.apiModels"
enablePostProcessFile = true
skipOverwrite = false
typeMappings = [
        OffsetDateTime: "ZonedDateTime"
]
importMappings = [
        "java.time.OffsetDateTime" : "java.time.ZonedDateTime"
]
configOptions = [
        configPackage       : "com.abc.xyz.apiEndpoints.config",
        java11              : "true",
        dateLibrary         : "java8-localdatetime",
        serializationLibrary: "jackson",
        library             : "spring-boot",
        useBeanValidation   : "true",
        interfaceOnly       : "true",
        serializableModel   : "true",
        useTags             : "true"
]
}
```

I've tried to some of the suggestions here too: [Use java.time.Instant to represent DateTime instead of OffsetDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237650/use-java-time-instant-to-represent-datetime-instead-of-offsetdatetime)

but either it resulted in compilation errors or the type would go from `LocalDateTime` to `Object` as opposed to `ZonedDAteTime`.

This is part of the swagger.yaml:

```
parameters:
    - name: If-Modified-Since
      in: header
      description: If-Modified-Since
      required: false
      type: string
      format: date-time
```

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to use a local time to express `If-Modified-Since`. Do you have influence on the provider of the API? It should be expressed as UTC.

Comment: change the dateLibrary to just "java8" without the localdatetime